# Where i can add redirect page in php?

Tags: php

Hi in the below code I want to add a redirect page in both cases failed or success. Where do I need to put the code?

```
 <?php

// (A) PROCESS ORDER FORM
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
  require "process.php";
  echo $result == ""
    ? "<div class='msg'>Thank You! We have received your order</div>"
    : "<div class='msg'>$result</div>" ;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how someone can redirect to page.

```
 <?php

// (A) PROCESS ORDER FORM
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
  require "process.php";
  echo $result == ""
    ? header ("Location: success.php") // SUCCESS PAGE GOES HERE
    : header ("Location: failed.php"); // FAILED PAGE GOES HERE
}

?>
```

Comment: See also: https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/php-redirect or https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/php-redirect